# Is logging into Sitecore from another computer on the same network possible for an XP0 installation?

Tags: login, setup

I have installed Sitecore 9.2 XP0 Single on a server and I'm trying to log in to the instance as admin from a different computer. The home page of the Sitecore instance loads fine at the address http://mysite.com, but when I try to access http://mysite.com/sitecore/ to log in it redirects and ends up saying "This site can't be reached" at mysite.identityserver/connect/authorize?client_id=Sitecore&...........

Is XP Scaled XP1 installation required to access from a different computer? If this is possible in XP0, where can I find information to help me get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

To make sure that your local computer has access to these sites you need add the this 2 entries to your local **hosts** (on Windows: `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`) file:

```
<internal IP address of the Sitecore server> mysite.identityserver
<internal IP address of Sitecore server> mysite.com
```

If you want to set the mysite.identityserver and mysite.com reachable for everyone in the same network you need to setup a DNS server.

The difference between XP0 and XP1:

- XP0 (XP Single): single instance, which means you have all services installed as one as possible
- XP1 (XP Scaled): scaled instance, which means you have all services installed as scaled as possible

The topology does not do anything with from where you can access the sites. [Here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/pre-built-topologies.html) you can find more information about predifined topologies.

Comment: Thanks so much Tamás! I could not get this working on my work computer. I tried on my home network and computer, and after adding the 2 entries I was able to log in from a different computer.

Comment: @Gabe the servers has probably a different internal IP addresd than a public. Try the same IP address which you use to reach them from internal network.

Comment: I had to go through the IT department to get this resolved on the server at work. Turns out they have a DNS server, and we were able to get it working. Thanks again!